Biblical speaker references
The question What are all of the instances in which Christ discusses marriage? initially seems maybe off topic.
I say maybe:

limited to Jesus' words about a specific topic (won't be a book about it)
biblical-basis is on topic (this meta has an interesting discussion on biblical-basis vs bible says, IMO what a speaker says in bible leans more towards biblical-basis than bible says)
rest of question clarifies exactly what they're looking for (see below)

However the question at the end:

Are there any other examples of Christ discussing the topic of erotic love/marriage aside from this discussion around divorce/eunuchs?

Seems less off topic.
One vote to close mentions its a text search and should be closed. I'm not seeing text searches as off topic, though thinking about it, I agree general text searches asking for all instances would be off topic. This question seems to limit the scope (by speaker) and the topic (with omissions), which I feel like helps narrow the answer into something that is answerable or in scope.
My question(s) is kind of a conglomerate.

Are text search questions off topic?

What if they're scoped?
Any references in help/meta?


Is asking what what/where a speaker speaks about a subject off topic?

how is this not biblical-basis?



See also

Real Questions Have Answers
Are questions asking for verse searches salvageable or off-topic? (the answer here IMO leans towards indicating this question would be on topic since it's about a specific doctrine)


These questions can easily be answered with a search engine. A text search question is not about Christian doctrine, it's just about the Bible. Which I would call prima facie Christian evidence, not doctrine.
To search things out in the Bible does not require exegesis or interpretation or the exercise of religious authority or the inspiration of the Holy Spirit or anything that constitutes the meat of what we answer on this site, therefore I'd say it is always off topic.
If part of the question is off topic and the other part is not, I think you can edit out the part that is off topic and see if the OP likes it - since that's not substantially changing the question - it's just removing the parts that are off topic. but you're not obliged to do that.

lots of questions can easily be answered with a search engine (https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/72/22319, https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/4464/22319, etc). I feel like its a stretch to say its not about Christian doctrine, in that not only is it from the bible but looking for a teaching from Christ. Either way are there any Help articles that say this sort of question is off topic and how to distinguish?

I think about the kinds of questions that I, personally, would be more apt to turn to Google vs c.se for and "what does the Bible say about ... " are in the google domain - it's a judgement call, clearly, but that's my judgement :)
